# XLPagerTabStrip to add Image and label in IOs Swift View Pager

Tags: ios, swift, xlpagertabstrip

I am making an app with View pager app, I am using  XLPagerTabStrip library for making it. It works fine with Title in the Viewpager item. I want to add Icon and corresponding Label in it.

Answer (score 7):

There reason behind the crash is, the UIImageView is missing in the ButtonCell.xib.

Solution is:

1. Open ButtonBarViewCell class,from the top navigation menu of xcode,click on the ButtonBarViewCell.There you can see the ButtonCell.xib.
2. Open ButtonCell.xib,drag and drop a UIImage view at the center of the cell.Apply Constrains.and connect it to the IBOutlet imageView.
3. Go back to ButtonBarViewCell class and Add this line of code inside 
   func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) function.

> if imageView.superview != nil {
>              contentView.addSubview(imageView)
>           }

4.Go back to the class implementing the page and add this code

```
 func indicatorInfo(for pagerTabStripController: PagerTabStripViewController) -> IndicatorInfo {
    return IndicatorInfo(title: "",image: UIImage(named: "camera.png"))
}
```

5.done

`